# Given two 32-bit numbers, N and M, and two bit positions, i and j. Write a method to set all bits between i and j in N equal to M

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

> You are given two 32-bit numbers, N and M, and two bit positions, i
>   and j. Write a method to set all bits between i and j in N equal to M
>   (e.g., M becomes a substring of N located at i and starting at j).
>   EXAMPLE: Input: N = 10000000000, M = 10101, i = 2, j = 6 Output: N =
>   10001010100

This problem is from Cracking the Coding interview. I was able to solve it using the following O(j - i) algorithm:

```
def set_bits(a, b, i, j):
    if not b: return a
    while i <= j:
        if b & 1 == 1:
            last_bit = (b & 1) << i
            a |= last_bit
        else:
            set_bit = ~(1 << i)
            a &= set_bit
        b >>= 1
        i += 1
    return a
```

The author gave this O(1) algorithm as a solution:

```
def update_bits(n, m, i, j):
    max = ~0 # All 1s

    # 1s through position j, then zeroes
    left = max - ((1 << j) - 1)

    # 1s after position i
    right = ((1 << i) - 1)

    # 1’s, with 0s between i and j
    mask = left | right

    #  Clear i through j, then put m in there 
    return (n & mask) | (m << i)
```

I noticed that for some test cases the author's algorithm seems to be outputting the wrong answer. For example for N = 488, M = 5, i = 2, j = 6 it outputs 468. When the output should be 404, as my O(j - i) algorithm does.

**Question: Is there a way to get a constant time algorithm which works for all cases?**

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? M = 5 has only 3 bit, so what should be populated from bit 6 to bit 2? 10100 or 00101 ?

Comment: @PhamTrung: Well in case `M = 5`, it's binary is `00...0101`, I think, so it has an arbitrary amount of leading zeros.

Comment: `m` should also be cleared after `j-i`

Comment: A C++ implementation showing the author's algorithm works well: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f73fe844cc236a6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the author of the algorithm assumes the bound of `j` (six in your example) to be *exclusive*; this boils down to the question whether a range from `2` to `6` should include `6` (in Python that is not the case). In other words, if the algorithm is modified to:

```
def update_bits(n, m, i, j):
    max = ~0 # All 1s

    # 1s through position j, then zeroes
    left = max - ((1 << (j+1)) - 1)

    # 1s after position i
    right = ((1 << i) - 1)

    # 1’s, with 0s between i and j
    mask = left | right

    #  Clear i through j, then put m in there 
    return (n & mask) | (m << i)
```

It works.

Nevertheless you can speed up things a bit as follows:

```
def update_bits(n, m, i, j):
    # 1s through position j, then zeroes
    left = (~0) << (j+1)

    # 1s after position i
    right = ((1 << i) - 1)

    # 1’s, with 0s between i and j
    mask = left | right

    #  Clear i through j, then put m in there 
    return (n & mask) | (m << i)
```

In this example, we simply shift the ones out of the register.

Note that **you made an error in your own algorithm**, in case `b = 0`, that does not mean you can simply return `a`, since for that range, the bits should be cleared. Say `a = '0b1011001111101111'` and `b = '0b0'` and `i` and `j` are `6` and `8` respectively, one expects the result to be `'0b1011001000101111'`. The algorithm thus should be:

```
def set_bits(a, b, i, j):
    while i <= j:
        if b & 1 == 1:
            last_bit = (b & 1) << i
            a |= last_bit
        else:
            set_bit = ~(1 << i)
            a &= set_bit
        b >>= 1
        i += 1
    return a
```

If I make this modification and I test the program with 10'000'000 random inputs, both algorithms always produce the same result:

```
for i in range(10000000):
    m = randint(0,65536)
    i = randint(0,15)
    j = randint(i,16)
    n = randint(0,2**(j-i))
    if set_bits(m,n,i,j) != update_bits(m,n,i,j):
        print((bin(m),bin(n),i,j,bin(set_bits(m,n,i,j)),bin(update_bits(m,n,i,j)))) #This line is never printed.
```

Of course this is not a *proof* both algorithms are equivalent (perhaps there is a tiny cornercase where they differ), but I'm quite confident that for valid input (`i` and `j` positive, `i < j`, etc.) both should always produce the same result.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is one mistake in the proposed solution.

It should be:

```
def update_bits(n, m, i, j):
    max = ~0 # All 1s

    # 1s through position j + 1, then zeroes
    left = max - ((1 << (j + 1)) - 1)

    # 1s after position i
    right = ((1 << i) - 1)

    # 1’s, with 0s between i and j
    mask = left | right

    #  Clear i through j, then put m in there 
    return (n & mask) | (m << i)
```

Because it said we should populate starting from `j` to `i`, so we need to clear bit `j` also. Result is 404 as expected.

To go a little bit further, in case `m` has more than `(j - i + 1)` bits, we need to change the return statement:

```
    return (n & mask) | ((m << i) & ~mask)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. **create mask `m` which has set bits for all bits between `<i,j>`**

   you can use arithmetic bit shift left to create powers of 2 exploiting that powers of 2 minus one are numbers with all set bits up to the exponent-1
   so set all bit `<0,j>` and then clear bits up to `i-1`
2. **copy bits from `M` to `N`**

   so use `m` to clear bits in `N` and then copy the `M` bits instead of them. Do not forget to shift left `M` by `i` to match your case...

In **C++** (sorry do not use python) is `O(1)` like this:

```cpp
DWORD bitcopy(DWORD N,DWORD M,int i,int j)
    {
    DWORD m;
    // set bits <0..j>
    m =(2<<j)-1;
    // clears <0..i)
    if (i) m^=(2<<(i-1))-1;
    // clear space for copied bits
    N&=0xFFFFFFFF-m;
    // copy bits M->N
    N|=(M<<i)&m;
    return N;
    }
```

You can also use **LUT** for the `i,j` bits parts of `m` instead... as you got 32 bit numbers it needs just 32 or 64 numbers if you are not comfortable with the bit shifts...

Answer (score 1):

This version seems to work well too, provided `i <= j`

```
def set_bits(n, m, i, j):
    mask = (1 << (j + 1)) - (1 << i)
    return n & ~mask | (m << i) & mask
```

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: @GaneshMS The mask is the integer which all bits having index in the range(i, j+1) are set and all the other bits are unset. Hence n & ~mask has the same bits as n except in that range where all the bits are unset, and (m << i) & mask has only the bits of m in that range.

Answer (score 0):

Its Easy,You can implement it at your own once you've idea what you have to do...

heres 32 bit example:

given:

n = 10000000000000000000000000000000

m = 10101

i=2 , j=6

Step 1: Create Mask ->

```
int x=(~0);              //All Ones 11111111111111111111111111111111   
int left=(1<<i)-1;       //                                       11
int right=x-((1<<j)-1);  //         11111111111111111111111111000000
int mask=left | right;   //         11111111111111111111111111000011
```

Step 2 : Clear bits between i and j in given number 'n' ->

```
int cleared = n & mask; //          10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Step 3 : Putting m in n between i and j (cleared bits) ->

```
int ans= cleared | m<<i;            10000000000000000000000001010100
```